# ClassCastException: cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Tags: android, fragment, classcastexception

I have a list in a fragment and I want a new activity to start when I press something in that list. I have only tried with my first option but when I try it I get the error:

```
03-20 15:16:13.017: E/AndroidRuntime(941): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.test.test.Algebra cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

Here's my fragment class:

```
public class FragmentTest extends SherlockListFragment {

String formler[]= {
        "Algebra",
        "Aritmetik",
        "Differential- och integralkalkyl",
        "Funktioner",
        "Geometri",
        "Komplexa tal",
        "Statistik och sannolikhet",
        "Trigonometri"
};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, formler));

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String choice = formler[position];
    try{
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Class choiceClass = Class.forName("com.test.test." + choice);
        Intent startIntent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), choiceClass);
        startActivity(startIntent);
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why are you trying to start a new activity like this? use switch and just change the class name in your intent and start it. no need to use  string array and do stuff like that

Comment: Show your code of `com.test.test.Algebra` please

Comment: It seems Algebra is not an Activity... Make sure that your Algebra class extends Activity..Also post Algebra class

Comment: please dont use getBaseContext.. call context any other way, getActivity(); should work

Comment: I simply never extended Activity in my Algebra class, which is almost empty currently, stupid of me... But thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that Algebra is extending an activity and also you can simple initiate  an activity like this `new Intent(currectActivity.this, Algebra.class);`

Comment: When I try that I get
The constructor Intent(FragmentMatte, Class<Algebra>) is undefined

Comment: Also the reason it's like that is so that it starts the activity of whichever lististem is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I never used a SherlockListFragment, but I used a Fragment. When I wanted to initialize a new fragment, I used

```
NewFragmentClass newFragment = new NewFragmentClass ();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.myCurrentFragmentId, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

I Hope this help

Comment: I'm going from a Fragment to an Activity, not another Fragment :)